# Fetch HTTP Request in React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I encountered an error when trying to make a HTTP request using Fetch from Android Emulator in React Native Expo.

[image]

[image]

It logs this message

[image]

The API is working fine in the browser.

Comment: can you share an expo snack link?

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@git/github.com/danielcm585/churchapp-frontend @Gaurav Roy

Comment: checking :) will update